# Off-canvas panel closes when removing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I am setting up a small shop using [**simpleCart.js**](http://simplecartjs.org) and [**Bootstrap 3**](http://getbootstrap.com). 
For displaying the cart I was hoping to use an off-canvas panel that I have enabled using the [**Jasny-bootstrap add-on**](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/). Everything works fine but when I eliminate elements from the cart the off-canvas panel closes. This way the user his unable to modify content in the cart without having to reopen the panel after each click. How can I keep the panel open until ***the user chooses*** to close it?

**[Here is an FIDDLE demonstrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/tomtom/ba74L/2/)**

From looking at this snippet from [**(link straight to code)**](http://nr.x10.mx/js/simpleCart.js) simpleCart.js - line 337-353, am I right in assuming that once you remove an item it reloads the cart and therefore it causes the panel to close? If this is the case, then how would a version of this code look like to fix my problem?

```
                // empty the cart
            empty: function () {
                // remove each item individually so we see the remove events
                var newItems = {};
                simpleCart.each(function (item) {
                    // send a param of true to make sure it doesn't
                    // update after every removal
                    // keep the item if the function returns false,
                    // because we know it has been prevented 
                    // from being removed
                    if (item.remove(true) === false) {
                        newItems[item.id()] = item
                    }
                });
                sc_items = newItems;
                simpleCart.update();
            },
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `autohide` controls if the navbar should be closed when a user clicks outside of it. Setting it to `false`, means it stays open until the user clicks on the 'CLOSE PANEL HERE' link.

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ba74L/3/)

Note that normally the navmenu doesn't close when clicked on a link inside of it. I'm not sure why this is happening in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the ultra clear answer.. and thank you for your wonderful bootstrap add-on :)